# How to obtain a version of ImageMagick compiled for OpenCL (Linux)

Tags: linux, imagemagick

For reasons I do not understand, ImageMagick requires a special compilation to make use of OpenCL drivers on the host machine.

Does anyone know of a place where I can obtain a Linux version compiled for 'modern' computers with GPUs?

Comment: Could you not compile it yourself?

Comment: I have no clue what I'm doing and no one has a dummies guide. I find Linux much less accessible than any other tech I've worked with. I just imagined it would be compiled already to use either AMD or NVidia OpenCL drivers.

Comment: @stib The problem I have is that setting the `--enable-opencl` flag while running `./configure` doesn't actually enable opencl. And information about it online in sparse.

You wouldn't by any chance know more?